# Combining two CouchDB indexes with the same key?

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

In my application, users can submit forms. I have two design documents. The first one says how many times a specific form has been submitted:

```
map: function(doc) { emit( doc.form_id, 1 ) };
reduce: _sum
```

The second one gives the most recent submission time.

```
map: function(doc) { emit( doc.form_id, doc.created ) };
reduce: function (keys, values) { return Math.max.apply(null, values) }
```

Is there a way to combine/join the two design documents based on the key (`form_id`), or do I have to do two separate requests, and then combine the results in code?

Comment: Have you tried the [builtin reduce function](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/ddocs.html#builtin-reduce-functions) called `_stats` ? You could use it to get both `max` and `count`.

Comment: Do you want to call one particular form_id finally or ALL at once?

Comment: @Aurélien - I had, but I looked at `sum`, saw it was summing the timestamps, and didn't look at literally the next result to see `count` was there. Thanks.